# Send and receive text data in background thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-handler

I'm new in developing for Android. My app is client whith outside TCP server. I need to send text data from EditText to server in background thread with Socket. Answer from server i need to add to TextView. I see many examples, but don't see example which i could understand. So i need simple example specially for me, as that possible. Sorry for my English.
AsyncTask only for one-time using. I need only Thread. As i understand i need: Thread(Runnable), Handler, Message, Looper.. But i don't understand how use all this classes for me.

```
ublic class ServerWork extends Thread{

public static final Character PREFIX = ###;
public static final Character SUFFIX = ###;
public static final int SERVERPORT = ###;
public static final String SERVER_IP = ###;

private Socket socket;
String response;
String inputStr;

public ServerWork(String inputStr){
    this.inputStr = inputStr;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
        socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

        String str = PREFIX  + inputStr + SUFFIX;
        PrintWriter printOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                true);

        BufferedReader inputBuffer = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( socket.getInputStream() ) );

        printOut.println(str);
        printOut.flush();

        char buf[] = new char[ 1000 ];
        int count = inputBuffer.read( buf );
        response = new String( buf, 0, count );


    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.Attach some of the code snippets you have tried yet.

Comment: When you say background thread - do your require your GUI to be interactive or do you want to block your UI when you are doing the background thread? The best bet would be to use an async task - however that will essentially block your UI with a Dialog box which determines the progress. If you want your GUI to be interactive use a Handler thread.

Comment: If you need permanent connection you should make those async task operations on a service.

Comment: i think you need to use a Service, then either `bind` to this service or send `broadcast` for communication between service and UI